# git checkout binary file using object SHA (not commit SHA)

Tags: git

I will be deleting video files from a git repo (using BFG). Before I delete them, I want to extract them and back them up. I have a list of these objects and their object SHAs.

```
ce6c93a3389b    4.4MiB      Fixasr/part01/ToFix.mp4                     
3cf7cff4e087    5.7MiB      Fixasr/part03/ToFix.flac            
028fd658bcc5    6.0MiB      Selectmen (3 minutes).webm          
ea3fa8f8dc9a    6.0MiB      Fixasr/part01/ToFix.flac
... etc  ...
```

I can easily extract a text file using "git cat-file" and get back the identical text file:

```
git cat-file -p e13b31 >textfile.txt
```

But if I try this with a binary file, the output is invalid. If my binary file is 9 MB, the output file is about twice that, 18 MB! I also tried using:

```
git cat-file blob 53f6e >video.mp4
```

But I get the same result.

I experimented with a tiny binary file to see what was happening. My file contained:

```
00 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 ...
```

When I extract this file using "git cat-file" it contains the following:

```
FF FE 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 ...
```

It appears to be trying to convert the binary file to Unicode text by converting each "2-byte character" into 4 bytes!

Most likely git itself does not use the plumbing command "cat-file" when it checks out binary files. Does anyone know what commands, git itself actually uses?

Comment: Try `git show blob_sha > filename`

Comment: If you're using powershell, that's my top suspect..

Comment: @fredrik I tried "git show ..." The output is the same as the others. It expands all 2-bytes to 4-bytes.

Comment: @jthill You are exactly right. When I switch from powershell to bash, "git cat-file" works! -- whether I use "blob" or "-p".

Answer (score 4):

This is powershell corrupting your data. I'd recommend not staying at hotels where the bellhops open and repack all your luggage, damaging everything that doesn't match their expectations.

Comment: Yes, that's the main disadvantage of staying at a Microsoft resort. I can't be sure of what they'll do with my stuff.

Comment: Can confirm this is true, I just git cat on a binary in powershell and had to redo it in git bash.